# VBA VLOOKUP Copy/Paste

Tags: vba, vlookup

I have a VBA code that copies and pastes pages and copies everything properly except any cell that has a vlookup. I don't know what the problem is or if there may be some lag time. Any ideas would be helpful.

```
Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
Set thisSheet = Application.ActiveSheet

Dim templateSheet As Worksheet
Set templateSheet = Worksheets("Template ")

Dim baseSheet As Worksheet
Set baseSheet = Worksheets("Base")

Dim wrkBook As Workbook
Set wrkBook = ActiveSheet.Parent

Dim wrkSheet As Worksheet

Dim sNewSheetName As String
Dim nRow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rRunRange As Range
Set rRunRange = Range("Cohorts_to_Run")

Dim n As Integer

For nRow = 1 To rRunRange.Rows.Count

    sNewSheetName = rRunRange.Cells(nRow, 2).Value

    Set wrkSheet = Worksheets.Add(, Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    wrkSheet.Name = sNewSheetName

    'Set parameters to pickup data....
    Dim zZoom As Double
    zZoom = ActiveWindow.Zoom

    templateSheet.Activate
    templateSheet.Range(baseSheet.Range("TEMPLATE_COPY_RANGE").Value).Copy

    wrkSheet.Activate
    wrkSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    wrkSheet.Paste
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = baseSheet.Range("ZOOM_LEVEL").Value

    wrkSheet.Range("A1").RowHeight = 10

    Application.CutCopyMode = False


    wrkSheet.Range("B2").Value = Range("Cohorts_to_Run").Cells(nRow, 1).Value

    Dim sTitleRangeName As String
    sTitleRangeName = sNewSheetName & "_Title"

    wrkSheet.Range(baseSheet.Range("TEMPLATE_COPY_RANGE").Value).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wrkSheet.Range(baseSheet.Range("TEMPLATE_COPY_RANGE").Value).PasteSpecial         
    xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
 Next nRow
```

Comment: You're going to need to post your suspect code for us to know what the problem is too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I assume your confusion is that last line which pastes only values and removes any formulas.

```
wrkSheet.Range(baseSheet.Range("TEMPLATE_COPY_RANGE").Value).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Why not just paste? `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` will remove your formulas everytime. That's the point.

```
Dim copyRange as Range, pasteRange as Range
Set copyRange = wrkSheet.Range(baseSheet.Range("TEMPLATE_COPY_RANGE").Value)
Set pasteRange = wrkSheet.Range(baseSheet.Range("TEMPLATE_COPY_RANGE").Value)
copyRange.Copy pasteRange
```

You're `wrkSheet.Range(baseSheet.Range("TEMPLATE_COPY_RANGE").Value)` syntax is confusing though. Is there the name of another range in your named range `TEMPLATE_COPY_RANGE`?